# Login Required Decorator with Many Possible HTML's for Same URL

Tags: python, django, login-required

I would like to restrict access to urls that are served by django generic views. I have researched the login required decorator, but have only had partial success in getting it to work as I have a complication that is not addressed in the docs (or at least I couldn't find it).

Before adding the decorator, in urls.py I have the following:

```
url(r'^search/(?P<search_type>\w+)', search)
```

The above named search function is slightly complex in that depending on various conditions, it will render one of four possible html pages.

I don't see in the docs a way to handle multiple html pages using the decorator, and I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

I have tried using the decorator with one of the four html pages, and it does work for that one html page:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

url(r'^search/(?P<search_type>\w+)',
    login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='search_form.html',), search)),
```

But how do I require login for all the possible html's?  For example, I tried things like:

```
 url(r'^search/(?P<search_type>\w+)',
    login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='search_form.html',), TemplateView.as_view(template_name='search_form_manual.html',), search)),
```

I also tried subclassing the generic views:

//in view.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class AboutView(TemplateView):
template_name_1 = "search_form.html"
template_name_2 = "search_form_manual.html"
template_name_3 = "search_results.html"
template_name_4 = "tag_search_results.html"
```

//in urls.py

```
from views import AboutView

url(r'^search/(?P<search_type>\w+)',
    login_required(AboutView.as_view(template_name_1, template_name_2,), search)),
```

But I get errors that template_name_1 and template_name_2 do not exist...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Regardless of the decorator usage, I don't see how you can replace your `search()` function-based view with a single `TemplateView` if you need to use multiple templates. What's wrong with `url(r'^search/(?P<search_type>\w+)', login_required(search))`?

Comment: What view is handling your search function requests before you set logins to be required?  That's the view you should decorate.

Comment: login_required(search) works fine - thank you. I didn't realize I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-the-class) with class view

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    template_name_1 = "search_form.html"
    template_name_2 = "search_form_manual.html"
    template_name_3 = "search_results.html"
    template_name_4 = "tag_search_results.html"
```